# Accessing assemblies in directory other than bin from razor view pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, view, .net-assembly, probing

I have a simple ASP.NET MVC 4 Project. I want to load assembly from 'lib' folder in root of my project instead of 'bin' folder.

I add `<probing privatePath="lib" />` to my web.config. I have `custom.dll` in 'lib' folder.
Now i can write `using custom.namespace` in my classes and it works fine but i cannot add this namespace in razor view pages.

In other words `@using custom.namespace` in my razor view does not work. If i place above dll in 'bin' folder (not 'lib' folder), I can use it in view pages.

How can i load assembly in razor view page when i use probing in web.config?